# Only sub out non-alphanumeric characters in regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to remove symbols from this string in Python using re.sub:

```
re.sub(r"(?![a-z0-9])", "_", "some:long:str-:that:can't+have+symbols".lower())
```

The answer I'm looking for is:

`some_long_str__that_can_t_have_symbols`

but it doesn't work. I can definitely match alphanumeric characters using findall() then join() to make a new string, but that eliminates the character entirely, so I end up writing some inefficient for loop.

I think the problem is in how I negate my expression. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this [`[^a-z0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/MLb4fL/1)

Comment: Why are you using a lookahead instead of just matching what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like:

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"([^a-z0-9])", "_", "some:long:str-:that:can't+have+symbols".lower())
print(result)
```

Output:

```
some_long_str__that_can_t_have_symbols
```